# iPhone, if allowed notification, how to know user choose

Tags: iphone, notifications, push, uialertview

One of our company's iPhone applications uses a push notification the first time the user install the application. The notification pops up a system alertView to ask the user if its allowed receiving push notification.

My Question is how to know the user pressed "allowed" or "not allowed".

Answer (score -1):

For remote notifications -- If the registration succeeded, your application delegate will get a callback to this method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

If it failed, the callback will instead come to this method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Note that there are reasons the registration could fail other than the user pressing the "not allowed" button.  See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken%3a) for more information.

Comment: `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` is not called, when the user is pressing the deny button.
While it is possible to find out, what rights are given by calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]`, I have not found any way yet, to find this out through a callback.